# Extracting verbs except for the POStag from text with POS tag in R

Tags: r

I am new in R. I tried to gather the verbs ("/VB","/VBD","/VBG","/VBN","/VBP","/VBZ") using "openNLP" package (Note that 'udpipe' does not work in my environment). I have a sentence mixed with the tag as below.

> "Doing/VBG work/NN as/IN always/RB ./. playing/VBG soccer/NN is/VBZ good/JJ ./. I/PRP do/VBP that/IN"

How can I achieve the verbs without POS tags? The answer I am trying to get in this example is

> "doing", "playing", "is", "do"

Comment: Why doesn't udpipe work?

Comment: I received an error with using udpipe for doing pos tagging due to my bulky dataset volume. This example may be fine.

Comment: You might want to read https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/udpipe/vignettes/udpipe-parallel.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### your requested example:

```
    x <- "Doing/VBG work/NN as/IN always/RB ./. playing/VBG soccer/NN is/VBZ good/JJ ./. I/PRP do/VBP that/IN"
    x <- strsplit(x, split = " ")
    x <- unlist(x)
    x <- lapply(x, FUN = function(data){ 
        x <- strsplit(data, split = "\\/")
        x <- unlist(x)
        data.frame(token = x[1], xpos = x[2], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    })
    x <- do.call(rbind, x)
    subset(x, xpos %in% c("VB","VBD","VBG","VBN","VBP","VBZ"))
```

##### using udpipe

```
library(udpipe)
txt <- c(doc1 = "Doing work as always. playing soccer is good. I do that")
x <- udpipe(txt, object = "english", udpipe_model_repo = "bnosac/udpipe.models.ud", trace = 100)
subset(x, xpos %in% c("VB","VBD","VBG","VBN","VBP","VBZ"))

> subset(x, xpos %in% c("VB","VBD","VBG","VBN","VBP","VBZ"))
   doc_id paragraph_id sentence_id                sentence start end term_id token_id   token lemma upos xpos
1    doc1            1           1   Doing work as always.     1   5       1        1   Doing    do VERB  VBG
6    doc1            1           2 playing soccer is good.    23  29       6        1 playing  play VERB  VBG
8    doc1            1           2 playing soccer is good.    38  39       8        3      is    be  AUX  VBZ
12   doc1            1           3               I do that    49  50      12        2      do    do VERB  VBP
                                                   feats head_token_id dep_rel deps misc
1                                           VerbForm=Ger             0    root <NA> <NA>
6                                           VerbForm=Ger             4   csubj <NA> <NA>
8  Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin             4     cop <NA> <NA>
12                      Mood=Ind|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin             0    root <NA> <NA>
```